# How do I add the ability to change font size in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

I'm trying to install the [CKEditor Font Size Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/ckeditor_font) in my my editor. I installed the module via `composer` and then proceeded to copy the `font/plugin.js` file from [the Font Plugin's page](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/font) into `libraries/` in my document root, per the instructions.

I also threw in a `console.log()` call into the `font/plugin.js` file to make sure it was loading. I modified the configuration of the Basic HTML editor to include the font size and family buttons in the toolbar on the `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html` page of my site. When I go to create a piece of content that uses the Text Editor, I don't see the font/size buttons I've configured.

Checking the Javascript console, I see my log message so I know the `font/plugin.js` file is being loaded. There are no error messages in the console. **Why would the buttons not be showing up in this case?**

Comment: What about when uyou try the Full HTML filter?

Comment: @Kevin Oh, interesting. I see them in Full HTML mode but not in Basic HTML. Why might that be the case?

Comment: It sounds like however those fonts are set, it might be rejected by the filter (like inline style tags) or depend on another plugin that might not be loaded by Basic HTML configuration. In these cases buttons won't show, I have seen this happen on some button plugins I've made before.

Comment: Maybe could be [related to this](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_font/issues/2900789#comment-12805811), have you applied the patch in #22 ?

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for the suggestion, I actually came across this already and the patch by the way is out of date. I believe Kevin was correct that it is the Basic HTML configuration that is not rendering the buttons. I'm testing it out and will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's comment was spot on and it was in fact the Basic HTML configuration that was preventing the button from rendering. Specifically, the filter "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" was the issue. The buttons rendered correctly in Full HTML mode so that was the hint.

In the filter configuration at the bottom of the `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html` page, I modified the allowed tags. By default the filter allows plain `span` tags without any attributes. However, this plugin uses span tags with inline `style` attributes. As a result, I had to change `<span>` to `<span style>` in Allow Tags list.

I can now see the font and size buttons in the editor, and using the tool injects HTML like the following:

```
<p>The <span style="font-size:72px;">Quick red</span> fox jumps over the lazy brown dog</p>
```